# Add extra field to iframe in grid view update table data option in kendo UI?

Tags: angularjs, iframe, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Think my database have 6 fields. I only show 4 fields and it's data in grid using `kendo UI`.
I also add toolbar to that grid(Buttons that add and edit for data). When I click that Edit button the `iframe` only show that 4 fields that show in the grid. But I need to add extra field to that `iframe`. So is that can do in `kendo UI` ???
If can someone suggest a way to do that ??

I also using `AngularJS` to this project...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer for this.....

I feel that I had search a wrong way..

The answer in here ...[Answer](http://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-popup-editor-with-additional-fields)